# JFrame absolute positioning - Use ContentPane as position reference

Tags: java, swing

With `setLayout(null)`, I can tell my components to be at e.g. x 5 and y 60. However, this references to the window's x and y position, borders included.

Can I, somehow, tell my components that `0,0` is `contentPane`'s upper left (visible) corner?

This is especially annoying since different OS have different sized window borders.

Code initialising the JFrame:

```
JFrameAdd addFrame;
addFrame = new JFrameAdd();
addFrame.setVisible(true);
addFrame.setTitle("Vokabeltrainer");
addFrame.setResizable(false);
addFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
addFrame.setBounds(100, 100, 825, 585);
addFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

inside JFrameAdd.java:

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(settingsIcon));
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFrameGenerated.settingsFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 510, 36, 36);       
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
```

All code is here: https://github.com/MisterSkilly/Vokabeltrainer/tree/LoadSave/Latein%20asterisk/src and yes I know I shouldn't run two `JFrame`s simultaneously, but changing that messed things up and I don't have the time to change that ATM.

Comment: That is not a `SSCCE`, We can't compile and execute that code.

Comment: What is the result you want to get? A button at `x=50` and `y=60` within a frame?

Comment: @user1803551 no, a universal contentpane (that is the same size on Mac OSX as Windows 8)

Comment: That is a given. What is the question then?

Comment: Not for me: http://i.imgur.com/uNL6keZ.png vs http://i.imgur.com/QpEWzb7.png and if that border at the bottom of the window counts as contentpane in Windows, how would I decrease the contentpane's height only for OSX so Windows and OSX have a similar looking GUI?

Answer (score 0):

> However, this references to the window's x and y position, borders included

No, it references the content pane, which does not include the titlebar and borders.

> Can I somehow tell my components that 0,0 is contentPane's upper left (visible) corner?

This is the default behaviour.

If you believe your application is behaving differently then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

The general rule is DON'T use a null layout. Let the layout manager worry about positioning the components.

Comment: Doing some testing now, takes longer than I thought.

Something that definitely seems off is that Eclipse's WindowBuilder shows my button outside of the visible area (http://is.gd/ZddP9P) while Windows 8 puts it there just fine (http://is.gd/IVNs4W) I changed the position manually to line it up with Windows 8's layout

Comment: EDIT: On a Mac: http://is.gd/XqZI50

EDIT2: Changing the setBounds(100,100,825,585) to setBounds(100,100,825, 555 ) does no good either: http://is.gd/4t1KNH

Comment: What layout manager do you recommend that still lets you put all components relatively accurate and doesn't take ages to convert to from null layout?

Comment: I never use just one layout manager. I use a different layout manager or combination of layout managers depending on the requirement. Read the tutorial on [Layout Managers]() to learn the basics and for working example. Don't post pictures, post the code, that is the point of a `SSCCE`. We need to see the code to see if you are doing anything wrong and then maybe we can make suggestions. Post the code with your question. You can edit the question.

Comment: @Skilly The missing link for [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).